# 【The editor is used within the VUE】I cannot use v-model to bidirectional bind text in the Editor. I cannot get the text in the Editor

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, tui

When I use the tui. Editor, I cannot use the V-Model binding value in the VUE, it has no effect

```
   <editor v-model="ruleForm.content" />
```

script

```
data() {
            return {
                
                ruleForm: {
                    title: '',
                    description: '',
                    'content': 'my is editor！！！！'
                },
        },
}
```

Can someone help me？？？？

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what editor you are using. I recommend you check their documentation for events.
In my case, I used **suneditor** and i had to do:

`+ editor.onChange = (content, core) => app['content'] = content`;

as opposed to:

`<textarea v-model="content"></textarea>`

and that's how I did my own model binding.
I hope this helps.